# Quick way to view list of members in a class in Visual Studio 2008? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I know about the Class View window, which is great, but with over 200 classes in my "solution" and multiple sub-projects it's a pain to navigate.

Is there any quick way (keystroke perhaps?) of pulling up the list of members for the class I am currently looking at in the editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a drop down list in the upper right hand corner of the screen that lists all members for that class in alphabetic order...
[image]

Comment: Sigh...  Yes there it is.  I must have dismissed it as part of the visual noise of the environment...

Comment: Sometimes I make it a point to spend an hour or two wondering through all the menus and options of VS just to see what is there and if I can find some hidden feature.

Answer (score 0):

i would also recommend getting ReSharper to help you navigate your projects.
For example, clicking Ctrl+Alt+T allows you to enter a type name and get a wildcard result of all matching types in the solution... That feature alone is worth $200

Comment: I concur about ReSharper! It is awesome :)

Comment: lol @spender. The user name vs. the comment! The irony!
Actually, the feature cost comparison above was a bit of hyperbole. The personal edition of R# costs $200 (last i checked) and brings an incredible amount of productivity. As far i'm concerned, it pays for itself in hours, not weeks.